# Chessboard using matrices to PMG

Tags: c++, c

I need some help, I'm coding this for a chessboard in pixels 24x24, in normal chess has 8x8 square, so 24/8, because each pixel receive 0 or 1, I need mount it like `Desired output` and after i user this output to create a image in PMG. more details about pmg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format

## Desired output

```
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ]
```

## Current output

```
0  0  0 
1  1  1 
0  0  0 
1  1  1 
0  0  0 
1  1  1 
0  0  0 
1  1  1 
0  0  0 
1  1  1 
0  0  0 
1  1  1 
0  0  0 
1  1  1 
0  0  0 
1  1  1 
0  0  0 
1  1  1 
0  0  0 
1  1  1 
0  0  0 
1  1  1 
0  0  0 
1  1  1
```

## Code

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
     int l = 24,c = 24, tam = 0, check=0;

     printf("P2\n");

     printf("%d %d\n", l,c);
     printf("1\n");

     for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        tam=0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++) {
            if(check == 0){

                while (tam < (c/8)){
                    tam++;
                    printf(" 0 ");
                }
                check = 1;

            }else{

                while (tam < (c/8)){
                    tam++;
                    printf(" 1 ");
                }
                check = 0;

            }

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things wrong with your code:

1. You need to reset `tam` each inner loop, not each outer loop.
2. You need to shorten the inner loop by one iteration (`<` instead of `<=`).
3. You need to swap the starting value for `check` at the end of every third row.

I've made those three changes while making minimal other changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int l = 24,c = 24, tam = 0, check=0;

    printf("P2\n");

    printf("%d %d\n", l,c);
    printf("1\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
           tam=0;
           if(check == 0){

               while (tam < (c/8)){
                   tam++;
                   printf(" 0 ");
               }
               check = 1;

           }else{

               while (tam < (c/8)){
                   tam++;
                   printf(" 1 ");
               }
               check = 0;

           }

       }
       printf("\n");
       if(i%3 == 2)
           check = check == 1 ? 0 : 1;
   }
   return 0;
```

}

Produces output:

```
P2
24 24
1
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 
 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0 
 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0 
 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 
 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0 
 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0 
 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 
 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0 
 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0 
 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 
 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0 
 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0 
 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: A possible typo: where are the brackets `[]`?

Comment: Thank's @heathraftery. Don't need the `[ ]`. I use just for example.